# Exercise in Measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a measurable subset of $[0,1]$. Prove that If both $m(E)>0$ & $m(E^c)>0$, then there exists a point $p\in[0,1]$ such that for every neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in $[0,1]$, $m(E\cap U)>0$ & $m({E^c}\cap U)>0$.

I have the idea that $p$ must be chosen by constructing a nested sequence of closed intervals and then invoke the finite intersection property to complete the argument but have trouble start writing this in a proper manner. Any idea of how to begin writing this?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x\in [0,1],$ let $x\in S_1$ if there is an open subset $U$ of the $space$ $[0,1]$ such that $x\in U$ and $m(E^c\cap U)=0,$ and let $x\in S_2$ if there is an open subset $V$ of $[0,1]$ such that $x\in V$ and $m(E\cap V)=0.$

If $p$ does not exist then $S_1, S_2$ are non-empty disjoint open subsets of $[0,1]$ with $S_1\cup S_2=[0,1],$ contrary to the fact that $[0,1]$ is a connected space.

By  contrast, if we replace $[0,1]$ with $[0,1]\cup [2,3]$ and let $E=[2,3]$ then $p$ does not exist.

Note: Assume $p$ does not exist. Then $S_1\cup S_2=[0,1].$ Now if $S_1$ is empty then each $x\in E$ belongs to an open interval $V_x$ with rational endpoints such that $m(E\cap V_x)=0.$  The set of all open intervals with rational endpoints is countable  so $W=\{V_x: x\in E\}$ is countable. But then $0=\sum _{V\in W}m(E\cap V)\ge m(\cup_{V\in W}(E\cap V))=m(E),$ a contradiction. So if $p$ does not exist then $S_1$ (and similarly $S_2$) is not empty.

Comment: I don't understand why you have stated "...$U$  of the space $[0,1]$ such that $x\in U$ and $m({E^c}∩U)=0$,$ \mathbf{and}$ let $x∈S_2$ if there is an open subset $ \mathbf{V}$... "

Things I've mentioned in bold are unclear.

Comment: Why are $S_1$ and $S-2$ non-empty? There is a measurable set $E \subset [0,1]$ such that $0 <m(E\cap I) <m(E)$ for  every open intervaI $I$ in $[0,1]$. For such a  set $E$ your set $S_1$ is empty so connectedness argument does not hold.

Comment: @KaboMurphy . IF p does not exist THEN $S_1$ and $S_2$ are non-empty.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet As far as I can see non-existence of $p$ only implies that one of the sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ is non-empty.

Comment: @KaboMurphy . If $p$ does not exist and $S_1$ is empty then $S_2=[0,1]. $ The Lebesgue Density Lemma then implies $m(E)=0.$

Comment: @SL_MathGuy . I don't know what's unclear. Let $x \in S_1$ if (something), and let $x\in S_2$ if (some other thing).

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That is corrrect. I just wanted to tell you that an additional argument is required. You can now edit the proof and use the density argument. I am upvoting the answer.

Comment: @KaboMurphy . I added a very elementary extra part.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Looks fine now.